# use of -mcmodel=kernel flag in x86 platform

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, x86-64, red-zone

I am trying to cross compile a device driver built for x86 architecture to arm platform. It got compiled without any errors, but I dont think whole features are available. So I checked the makefile and found this particular part.

```
ifeq ($(ARCH),x86_64)
    EXTRA_CFLAGS += -mcmodel=kernel -mno-red-zone
```

This is the only part that depends on architecture it seems. After some time on google, I found that -mcmodel=kernel is for kernel code model and -mno-red-zone is to avoid using red zone in memory and both them were for x86_64. But its not clear to me, what impact does it make setting cmodel to kernel?

(Any insight into the problem with arm is also greatly appreciated.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The **x86 Options** section of the GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html) says:

> `-mcmodel=kernel`
>
> Generate code for the kernel code model. **The kernel runs in the negative 2 GB of the address space.**

(i.e. the upper 2GiB, addresses like `0xfffffffff0001234`)

In the kernel code model, static symbol addresses don't fit in 32-bit zero-extended constants (unlike the default small code model where `mov eax, imm32` (5 bytes) is the most efficient way to put a symbol address in a register).

But they *do* fit in sign-extended 32-bit constants, unlike the `large` code model for example.  So `mov rax, sign_extended_imm32` (7 bytes) works, and is the same size but maybe slightly more efficient than `lea rax, [rel symbol]`.

But more importantly `mov eax, [table + rdi*4]` works, because disp32 displacements are sign-extended to 64 bits.  **`-mcmodel=kernel` tells gcc it can do this but not `mov eax, table`**.

---

RIP-relative addressing can also reach any symbol from any code address (with a rel32 +-2GiB offset), so `-fPIC` or `-fPIE` will also make your code work, at the minor expense of not taking advantage of 32-bit absolute addressing in cases where it's useful.  (e.g. indexing static arrays).

If you didn't get link errors without `-mcmodel=kernel` ([like these](https://wiki.osdev.org/Building_libgcc_for_mcmodel%3Dkernel)), you probably have [a gcc that makes PIE executables by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux) (common on recent distros), so it avoids absolute addressing.